# Npm install hangs and fails on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

My npm installs on windows 10 with the most up to date node.js and npm stable versions always fail when I enter the command npm install while cd'd into my project folder. This specific folder was set up with express as described [here](https://stonesoupprogramming.com/2017/07/04/create-node-js-handlebars-express-js-project-from-command-line/). Below is the relevant portion of the verbose failure log. I have no idea what is going wrong, can anyone help?

1315 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\carte\Desktop\Queue\Queue\node_modules\amdefine' -> 'C:\Users\carte\Desktop\Queue\Queue\node_modules.amdefine.DELETE'
1316 verbose cwd C:\Users\carte\Desktop\Queue\Queue
1317 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
1318 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\carte\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--verbose"
1319 verbose node v8.11.0
1320 verbose npm  v5.8.0
1321 error path C:\Users\carte\Desktop\Queue\Queue\node_modules\amdefine
1322 error code ENOENT
1323 error errno -4058
1324 error syscall rename
1325 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\carte\Desktop\Queue\Queue\node_modules\amdefine' -> 'C:\Users\carte\Desktop\Queue\Queue\node_modules.amdefine.DELETE'
1326 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
1327 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had currently this problem and couldn't find answers, so I post my solution, in case it helps someone else.

My problem was that I have npm install on `C:\` and my project (or git folder) in `G:\.`
Moving my folder from `G:\` to `C:\Desktop` and running `npm install` solved it for me.

I am not sure if it was because of moving it to `C:\` or if it was because of moving it outside git-folder.

Edit: before that I actually cleaned npm cached using `--force`.
I'm using npm v6.7.0 and node v10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

which npm version you  are using, basically thses errors come with npm version below 5.5. For CLI

```
supporting information:
npm -v prints: 5.6.0
node -v prints: 8.9.1
npm config get registry prints: https://registry.npmjs.org/
Windows, OS X/macOS, or Linux?: Windows 10
```

Comment: I'm using 5.8.0

Comment: NPM 6.1.0 constantly hangs on my win7 machine.

Comment: Check here https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows for updating to the latest npm on Windows.check option3 may be help you Then try running your npm install command with maximum verbosity:
npm -ddd install -g grunt-cli

Answer (score 0):

In my case, npm install got stuck because I had TypeScript watching file in this directory. So the solution is to stop any tool that might be watching files and try again to install.